# Gin and middleware

Tags: go, middleware, go-gin

How to make a middleware so that it only works for some handlers (not for all)?
For example,

```
func (srv *server) Router(repository storage.Repository, cfg config.Flags) *gin.Engine {
 h := handlers.NewHandlerProvider()
 m := middlewares.NewMiddlewareProvider()
 srv.httpServer.Use(gin.Recovery())
 srv.httpServer.Use(m.LogHTTPHandler())
 srv.httpServer.POST("/", FirstHandler)
 srv.httpServer.GET("/qwe", SecondHandler)
 return srv.httpServer
}
```

I just want m.LogHTTPHandler() to work only with FirstHandler, not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gin.RouterGroup` to group all the routes that have common middlewares:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    // New returns a new blank Engine instance without any middleware attached.
    router := gin.New()

    g1 := router.Group("/")
    {
        // Add the logger middleware to group 1.
        g1.Use(gin.Logger())

        g1.GET("/", gin.HandlerFunc(func(ctx *gin.Context) {
            fmt.Println("FirstHandler")
        }))
    }

    g2 := router.Group("/qwe")
    {
        g2.GET("/", gin.HandlerFunc(func(ctx *gin.Context) {
            fmt.Println("/SecondHandler")
        }))
    }

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```